# Звук на системном динамике

Tags: аудио, динамик

Скажите, а можно ли воспроизвести звуковой файл, например WAV, на системном динамике (который пищит при запуске компьютера) в среде Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего нет, "Sound Driver for PC-Speaker" (специально предназначеный для этого драйвер) работает только в win9х или ME. Возможно кто-то его портировал для более поздних архитектур, но я об этом не слышал.